# adding a php custom field into a php code

Tags: php, image, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a PHP code on my wesbiste to get thumbnails of vimeo videos.
here is the code :

```
<?php
  echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb('43096888', 'thumbnail_large') . '" class="image_page_texte_et_medias" style="cursor:pointer" >';
  ?>
```

I'm using a ACF custom field with the video ID

```
<?php the_sub_field('vimeo'); ?>
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace the ID in my first php code ('43096888') by :

```
<?php the_sub_field('vimeo'); ?>
```

can anybody help me with this,

thanks a lot,

Comment: I'm not sure how your code works...how about: get_vimeo_thumb(the_sub_field('vimeo'), 'thumbnail_large') ??

Answer (score 1):

aren't you allowed to use variables as arguments? something like:

```
<?php
$foo = the_sub_field('vimeo');
  echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb($foo, 'thumbnail_large') . '" class="image_page_texte_et_medias" style="cursor:pointer" >';
  ?>
```

Comment: if it worked please set my answer as usefull :) Any other questions im happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb(the_sub_field('vimeo'), 'thumbnail_large') . '" class="image_page_texte_et_medias" style="cursor:pointer" >';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<img src="' . get_vimeo_thumb(the_sub_field('vimeo'), 'thumbnail_large') . '" class="image_page_texte_et_medias" style="cursor:pointer" >';
?>
```

You can simply replace the string `'43096888'` with your function `the_sub_field('vimeo')` if that's something what you want.